# Is iPhone GPS signal being smoothed?

Tags: ios, iphone, gps, cllocationmanager

I have been testing the GPS tracking on both iPhone and Android, and noticed some serious precision differences. The pictures present the two-way trip around few blocks. As you will see, android had tracked the differences between the movement directions - the lines do not align, while on iPhone, the route seems to perfectly align, which is highly unlikely, because the trip has been taken in two directions.

The purple line is from the Android device, the second one is from iPhone 7 Plus.

The question is - is iPhone doing any GPS smoothing, if so - is it possible to disable it?

I am using `kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation` and here is how I setup location manager:

```
        manager = CLLocationManager()
        manager?.delegate = self
        manager?.distanceFilter = 5.0
        manager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
        manager?.headingFilter = 1.0;
        manager?.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false

        if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            manager?.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
```

[image: Android tracking][image: iPhone tracking]

Comment: Did you drive or walk? Did you try to run the app on iPhone 6? Does it exhibit the same "snap to street map" behavior?

Comment: @AlexPavlov It was a drive - I started to suspect the motion coprocessor in the newer iPhones because the iPhone 6s gave the same outcome - I'll have to give it a go on some older device - nevertheless - This won't be an answer to the problem, as I'd like to make it work on the new hardware as well ;)